# Xamarin Forms custom stepper

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, stepper

I am trying to make a custom stepper to use in my listview such as this one
[image: Custom stepper]

Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you have already? Is this screenshot yours? What is the exact problem?

Comment: This is a custom stacklayout with 2 buttons and 1 entry in the middle the problem is that I need to get the value of this entry when changed. For example, In the regular stepper, I can easily use ValueChanged method and handle the value.

Comment: If it is a custom control, you will need to add your own events so that the page can subscribe to those...

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post your current implementation.

Comment: My implementation is the answer of "York Shen" I have the same custom class, I'm stuck at getting the value of the entry to use it in my code. I gave an example in the comment above that in the regular stepper you can easily use the "ValueChanged", but here I don't know how I can do that.

Comment: I used this answer: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140026/stepper-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1:

A `Stepper` allows inputting a discrete value that is constrained to a range. You could display the value of the `Stepper` using data binding in a label as follows :

Define in `XAML`:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Container">
    <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference stepper}" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    <Stepper Minimum="0" Maximum="10" x:Name="stepper" Increment="0.5" />
</StackLayout>
```

## Solution 2:

You could create a `BindableProperty` to implement this function, for example:

```
public class CustomStepper : StackLayout
{
    Button PlusBtn;
    Button MinusBtn;
    Entry Entry;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(
         propertyName: "Text",
          returnType: typeof(int),
          declaringType: typeof(CustomStepper),
          defaultValue: 1,
          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public int Text
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public CustomStepper()
    {
        PlusBtn = new Button { Text = "+", WidthRequest = 40, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 15 };
        MinusBtn = new Button { Text = "-", WidthRequest = 40, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = 15 };
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {

            case Device.UWP:
            case Device.Android:
                {
                    PlusBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
                    MinusBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
                    break;
                }
            case Device.iOS:
                {
                    PlusBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray;
                    MinusBtn.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray;
                    break;
                }
        }

        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        PlusBtn.Clicked += PlusBtn_Clicked;
        MinusBtn.Clicked += MinusBtn_Clicked;
        Entry = new Entry
        {
            PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray,
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric,
            WidthRequest = 40, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#3FFF")
        };
        Entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Text), BindingMode.TwoWay, source: this));
        Entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;
        Children.Add(PlusBtn);
        Children.Add(Entry);
        Children.Add(MinusBtn);
    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
            this.Text = int.Parse(e.NewTextValue);
    }

    private void MinusBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Text > 1)
            Text--;
    }

    private void PlusBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text++;
    }

}
```

For more detailed information, please refer to the following documents:

- [Stepper in Xamarin Forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140026/stepper-in-xamarin-forms)
- [Stepper Control In Xamarin.Forms Application For Android And UWP](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stepper-control-in-xamarin-forms-application-for-android-and-uwp/)
- [C# (CSharp) Xamarin.Forms.Stepper Code Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Xamarin.Forms/Stepper/-/php-stepper-class-examples.html)
- [Xamarin Forms Guide -- Stepper](https://guides.peruzal.com/xamarin-forms-guide/views/stepper/)

## Update:

In the `CustomStepper` class, the `Entry` value is binding with the `Text` property, so you could get the value of the entry via `customStepper.Text`.

For example:

```
<local:CustomStepper x:Name="MyCustomerStepper"/>
```

You could get its `Entry` value in your `xaml.cs` file via:

```
var yourCustomerStepperEntryValue = MyCustomerStepper.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: This exactly what I'm doing, I need to get this value of the entry to use it in the XAML.cs class.

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Comment: @mohammadanouti, you could get it via using `var yourStepperValue = stepper.Value;`.

Comment: I know well about custom renders and how to use them in XAML and so on, but the problem is I don't know how to implement it from scratch so please can you share me some code how can in XAML take the Entry of the custom Stacklayout I created to use it in the Xaml.cs file

Comment: please reply. Thank you in advance

Comment: @mohammadanouti, Coul you please elaborate a bit more about the feature you want to achieve?  :)

Comment: @mohammadanouti, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what you need to do when you are using it normally on the page, but the thing is that I'm using it in a listview and as u know items in listview can't access it directly.  Normal Stepper in a listview you can access it by using "ValueChanged" Method and can easily get the value by using e.NewValue in the "ValueChanged" method in the Xaml.cs file. But in my case, I can't access the CustomStepper directly from the listview, so is there a way to get the value of the text when this CustomStepper is placed in the listview. I hope you get my point and help me to solve it.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help and support, but I need your response as soon as possible.

Comment: @mohammadanouti, sorry for my late response, for your question, I think you could refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189391/when-i-click-the-event-on-outside-of-listview-switch-button-or-inside-of-listvie/53201677#53201677

Comment: @mohammadanouti, I haven't test it on my side, but I think they are the same issue

Comment: I tried before something similar to this, I placed a TapGestureRecognizer, ClickedGestureRecognizer and SwipeGestureRecognizer for the CustomStepper since its a stacklayout so every time I change the value it will be saved, but it is not entering any of these when tapping or clicking on the buttons or the entry :(

Comment: @mohammadanouti, I haven’t thought of a solution for the time being, if this is urgent for you, I suggest you to raise a new question in StackOverflow. Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: No problem, Thank you for your help. Ok i will

Comment: Thanks for this idea :)